# What is the purpose of having an __init__.py file with only doscstrings?

Tags: python, python-packaging, docstring

I'm looking at a plugin for Cinema 4D which uses the function

```
c4d.modules.tokensystem.FilenameConvertTokens(text,rpData)
```

I wanted to see what was happening in this function so I searched through the directory and found that tokensystem is a folder, and in that folder is only an __init__.py file. In it contains a bunch of defined functions. However, there isn't any real code in these functions, just docstrings explaining how the function works. For example:

```
def FilenameConvertTokens(path, rpData):
    """
    Converts tokenized path string to standard string by replacing all Tokens with correct values if found.

    :type path: str
    :param path: The original path filename.
    :type rpData: dict
    :param rpData:

        The data used to extract value for Tokens.  See :ref:`renderpathdata_dictionary`.

    :rtype: bool
    :return: The converted filename, or the original path if any error.
    """
```

How does this do anything? I can't find anywhere that this information might be going to in order to give the output it says it gives. What am I missing?

Comment: Please note that the `basic` tag is for questions about the BASIC programming language, **not** because you believe your question "is basic". In general, we don't tag questions for "difficulty" or anything like that, only for the concepts and technologies involved. Please read [ask] and make sure you understand that this is *not a discussion forum*; the difficulty of the question is *not important* - what's important is *clearly stating* the question, ensuring that it's [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and not a duplicate.

Comment: Anyway, this is probably just a stub being used to make the docstrings accessible (to the built-in `help` command, and to tools that generate HTML etc. documentation automatically). The actual code might be implemented in C, with the package acting as a wrapper to make it accessible in a Python program.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thanks for all your info. I'll try moving ahead knowing this might be how it's connecting.

Comment: I think @KarlKnechtel is probably right; the Python function appears to wrap a [corresponding C++ function](https://developers.maxon.net/docs/Cinema4DCPPSDK/html/group__group__tokensystemlibrary.html#ga37cef14db6f2bc02ca767137a37e6242).

Comment: @nneonneo Thanks for the link! I don't fully understand how it knows to connect to the C++ function from the init but at least I know that something like this can happen.